# Are there any U.S. airports that offer GCA (PAR/ASR) approaches?

Tags: air-traffic-control, approach, instrument-procedures, airport-operations

Are there any U.S. Civilian or Joint-Use (military/civilian) airports that currently offer either/both a  **PAR** (Precision Approach Radar) or an **ASR** (Airport Surveillance Radar) Ground Controlled Approach (GCA)?

Comment: Most military airports are happy to do it as long as you don’t touch the runway (unless it’s an emergency, of course). Why do you need a civil/joint airport?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there are many civilian or joint-use airports where ASR approaches are available. PAR approaches are less common; *some* are available at joint-use airports but the majority are at Naval or Marine Corps Air Stations, with the rest at Air Force Bases and Army Airfields. At some airports, the civilian radar approach control can provide an ASR approach while the military operates a PAR.

According to the October 7, 2021 [Terminal Procedures Publications](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/dtpp/) (check section N for published minima), radar approaches are available at the following airports:

(Civil airports are roman type, *joint-use are italic*, **military are bold**.)

| Airport | Approach |
| --- | --- |
| ABI | ASR |
| *ABQ* | ASR |
| ACT | ASR |
| *ACY* | ASR |
| AMA | ASR |
| ARW | ASR |
| AZO | ASR |
| **BAD** | ASR |
| *BGR* | ASR |
| BTR | ASR |
| **BIF** | ASR |
| BIS | ASR |
| *BLV* | ASR |
| CMI | ASR |
| CNW | ASR |
| CWF | ASR |
| *CYS* | **PAR** |
| **DAA** | **PAR** |
| *DLH* | ASR |
| **DYS** | ASR |
| **EDF** | ASR |
| ELP | ASR |
| **EOD** | ASR |
| EVV | ASR |
| EYW | ASR |
| **FBG** | **PAR** |
| **FBK** | **PAR** |
| *FHU* | **PAR** |
| *FSD* | ASR |
| **FRI** | **PAR** |
| *FWA* | ASR |
| *GPT* | ASR |
| GRB | ASR |
| **GRK** | **PAR** |
| **GRF** | **PAR** |
| GRR | ASR |
| **GTB** | **PAR** |
| **HOP** | **PAR** |
| HSV | ASR |
| HTS | ASR |
| **HUA** | **PAR** |
| *HUF* | ASR |
| ILM | ASR |
| *JAN* | ASR |
| *LAW* | ASR |
| LCH | ASR |
| LFT | ASR |
| **LSF** | **PAR** |
| **MGE** | ASR |
| *MGM* | ASR |
| MLU | ASR |
| *MOB* | ASR |
| **NBC** | **PAR** |
| **NBG** | **PAR** |
| **NCA** | **PAR** |
| **NDZ** | **PAR** |
| **NFG** | **PAR** |
| **NFL** | **PAR** |
| **NFW** | **PAR** |
| **NGP** | **PAR** |
| **NGU** | **PAR** |
| **NHK** | **PAR** |
| **NIP** | **PAR** |
| **NJW** | ASR |
| **NKT** | **PAR** |
| **NKX** | **PAR** |
| **NLC** | **PAR** |
| **NMM** | **PAR** |
| **NPA** | **PAR** |
| **NQI** | **PAR** |
| **NQX** | **PAR** |
| **NRB** | **PAR** |
| **NSE** | ASR |
| **NTD** | **PAR** |
| **NTU** | **PAR** |
| **NUC** | **PAR** |
| **NUW** | **PAR** |
| **NYG** | **PAR** |
| **NYL** | **PAR** |
| **NZY** | **PAR** |
| *OKC* | ASR |
| **OZR** | **PAR** |
| **PAM** | **PAR** |
| **POE** | **PAR** |
| *PSM* | **PAR** |
| PWA | ASR |
| PWG | ASR |
| RFD | ASR |
| ROW | ASR |
| RST | ASR |
| SHV | ASR |
| SJT | ASR |
| **SLI** | **PAR** |
| SPI | ASR |
| *SPS* | ASR |
| *STJ* | **PAR** |
| **SVN** | **PAR** |
| **SZL** | ASR |
| **TIK** | ASR |
| TLH | ASR |
| TOI | **PAR** |
| *TOL* | ASR |
| *TUL* | ASR |
| *TYS* | ASR |
| *VUJ* | **PAR** |
| **WRI** | **PAR** |
| Y19 | ASR |
| *YNG* | ASR |